# Is Meteor supported in VS Code?

Tags: meteor, visual-studio-code

Is this something Visual Studio Code needs to add or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve. Under the hood Meteor is a NodeJS application, which means Visual Studio has decent support for it. I personally prefer WebStorm (which e.g. connects helpers in templates with the JS template helpers and recognizes if they're used or not).

Comment: @Peter: Are you saying WebStorm has official support for Meteor architecture?

Comment: Yes it does: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio Code can provide intellisense and warnings for Meteor.  To get that you simply need to add the TypeScript definition file for Meteor to your project folder.  You don't need to be coding with TypeScript for this to work, it works just fine for JavaScript too.

An easy way to add that file is to use the [TypeScript Definition Manager](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).  Open a command prompt, navigate to your project folder and then type `tsd query meteor --action install`.  That will add all the necessary bits and you should see that the Meteor specific syntax is no longer green squiggly underlined in VS Code.

If you don't yet have TypeScript Definition Manager installed there's a good guide to that in the [official VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs).

There's also a lot of voices pushing for better Meteor support to be built into VS Code, it's currently the [16th most requested feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7755360-meteorjs-support).

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for debugging meteor app in IDE:

You can run your app in debug mode using `meteor debug` and then attach debugger to port number 5858, It should work for all type of node.js debuggers e.g. Visual Studio, Visual code, Webstorm etc because they all have "attach" debugger option next to "debug" option.

Answer (score 0):

- Jetbrains **Webstorm 9 & 10** also support Meteor: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/

There was project for **Visual Studio** available: https://meteortools.codeplex.com/, but it hasn't been maintained for about 2 years and sadly doesn't provide any releases / downloads.

Comment: Meteor Tools for Visual Studio is dead?

Comment: it is dead project and not even a download link.

Answer (score 0):

a working meteor react front end debug session
[image: a working meteor react front end debug session]

1 launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "attach to meteor",
        "port": 9229,
    }
]
```

}

note the port number is 9229

run with package.json script  "debug": "meteor debug"

`yarn run debug`